# SwiftUI Menu Element not displaying on older simulator Devices

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, ios-simulator

I have a basic Menu object in SwiftUI, code below, that works on all devices except the iPhone SE gen3. The preview text displays fine, but when I tap it no menu object appears. If I press and hold on the preview text I can see it get lighter, evidencing that its receiving the touch input, its just not displaying the associated menu.

I have looked through bug reports and Apple’s documentation, and it doesn’t seem like this has been addressed at all.

The menu works on all simulators except the SE model (including an iPhone 8, which has the same screen size + resolution), as well as a physical iPhone 11. Unfortunately, I don’t have an physical SE to test on

Has anyone run into this issue, know of a workaround, or know if it’s just an issue with the simulator?

I am running iOS 16.4, Xcode 14.3.1

```
Menu(“Test Menu”) {
   Text(“hi”)
   Text(“hello”)
   Text(“hello again”)
}
```

Comment: Update: After changing seemingly nothing, the iPhone 8 simulator no longer works. The menu is still showing up on other simulators. I have uninstalled + reinstalled the app, and restarted the simulator. Not sure what is going on